# How to communicate between a Repository and ViewModel class when Retrofit either fails or success with an requests?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

For many years I have been developing Android apps with the MVP pattern but I'm now trying to learn `MVVM` with `ViewModel` and `LiveData`

In the following example I'm not getting how I would communicate a failure or successful result upon a `POST` or `GET` request with `Retrofit`

Before with MVP I would with use a Listener to communicate presenter with either `listener.onTodoFetched()` or `listener.onTodoFetchError()` and then reacting differently based on which method gets called. Should I still communicate in this way with my `ViewModel` class?

**FetchTodoRepository.java**

```
public MutableLiveData<String> fetchTodo() {
    retrofitService.getRetrofitService().create(Endpoints.class).getTodo().enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                listener.onTodoFetched(response.body());     //ViewModel equivalent?
            } else {
                listener.onTodoFetchError(response.message());     //ViewModel equivalent?
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            listener.onTodoFetchError(t.getMessage());     //ViewModel equivalent?
        }
    });

    return mutableLiveData;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on answers and further research one could use the following methods:

- A plain Java listener between the classes
- RxJava
- Kotlin Higher Order functions.

Comment: It would be easier if you would use RX, twith RX you can just observe the response and post value when sucess/failure. But with the listeners, I would create LiveData vars in VM (1 for sucess(String) and 2 for error(enum)  for example. Then on your listener you can just post the data using method `postValue()` on your var. After that it's up to you if you would use DataBinding or observe LiveData in the fragment/Activity for changes.

Comment: So It wouldn't be wrong to use either `RxJava` or plain Java listeners to communicate between a `Repository` and `ViewModel` in `MVVM`?

Comment: Plain listeners are just fine and since you are still using Java, RxJava would be a way to go, however, I would also like to mention that if you are going to ever use Kotlin or coroutines, Retrofit supports suspending functions by default which makes easier to combine with the MVVM architecture and LiveData.

Comment: @RodrigoQueiroz So my method `fetchTodo()` doesn't actually have to return an Object of `MutableLiveData` If I'm returning the result with a Listener or RxJava back to the `ViewModel`

Comment: Have you read the [Exposing Network Status section of the Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake No, But I'm doing it now

Comment: Take a look at [Github Browser Sample with Android Architecture Components](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) sample project.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Would this sealed class work in Java? I suppose the three classes is equivalent to Java listeners

Comment: @Muddz - nothing quite as clean as Kotlin provides with sealed classes, but the same kind of approach works in Java, sure.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have made an example for to demonstrate my idea with  communicating Repository with ViewModel via simple listeners: https://gist.github.com/Muddz/e451572e2d2e46a8812e332bc1309966

On could take it to next level with RxJava instead of listeners

Answer (score 4):

Communication between Repository and ViewModel using [Higher-Oder Functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) 
Pass function as Argument into repository method

For Example in Repository method like this:

```
fun repoMethod(id : Int, viewModelCallBack : (List<CustomeDto>) -> Unit)
{
     //Your API call
     .....
    viewModelCallBack(response.body())

}
```

And View Model Method like

```
    fun viewModelMethod()
    {
       repoObj.repoMethod(5){ listOfValueReturnFromApi ->
            //Here listOfValueReturnFromApi is API response using Higher Order function in kotlin
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are using mvvm with livedata you really don't need to use interface to pass the data to viewmodel.

MutableLiveData has method setValue() pass your response in that and then when you will call this fetchTodo() method in viewmodel you will get all your data.

Try below code

```
  public MutableLiveData<String> fetchTodo() {
retrofitService.getRetrofitService().create(Endpoints.class).getTodo().enqueue(new 
Callback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
            mutableLiveData.setValue(response.body())
        } else {
             mutableLiveData.setValue(response.message());    
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
         mutableLiveData.setValue(t.message());    //ViewModel equivalent?
    }
});

return mutableLiveData;
}
```

In your viewmodel :

```
 public LiveData<String> fetchTodo()
{
 return yourRepoInstance.fetchTodo() ; here you will get result data
}
```

Comment: How do i distinguish between a sucesss and failure result as I would be able to do with the two different listeneres?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to implement.

Just use HTTP status code. In response you'll get status code, just send it to viewmodel and in viewmodel you can easily send it to Activity or fragment by observing it.

Eg. 200 - Ok
400 - Bad request etc.

I don't know it helps you or not but this thing works for me.